# pandas: Comparing dataframe rows and storing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one row. The first 5 columns are ID columns and the rest is the data:

```
0   1   865694  C   T   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

And another dataframe with many rows (of which here are a subset). The first three columns are ID columns and the rest are the data.

```
0   G   C   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   ...     3   3   3   1   3   3   3   3   3   3
1   T   G   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   G   A   3   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   ...     3   3   2   1   1   1   2   0   3   3
3   A   G   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   ...     3   3   3   1   3   3   3   3   3   3
4   C   T   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   G   A   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   A   G   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   C   T   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   ...     3   3   3   1   3   3   3   3   3   3
8   G   A   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   C   T   3   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   ...     3   3   2   0   1   1   2   0   3   3
10  G   A   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

In both dataframes the data columns can take values of 0, 1, 2 or 3.

I want to compare the first dataframe row with each row from the second data frame, counting occurrences of each combination. E.g. the number of 0,0 which would be the number of columns with 0 in the row of the first dataframe, and 0 in the row in question of the second dataframe. If this could be functionised it can be applied to each row.

What I would like returned is counts of the number of 00, 01, 02, 03, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 30, 31, 32, 33. This could be in the form of a list or a dataframe, the bigger issue is comparing the rows as I have ~2500 data columns.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't have any functioning code yet, but I am thinking about transposing the dataframes so that I can compare columns, by creating a function with numerous conditionals. E.g. if(df1[[1]]==0 & df2[[0]]==0): return 00. Still working on this for the moment!

Comment: Why don't you write up some code, see how far you get. If you get stuck in a few hours (or days), you can do some investigation, and then come back if you are still stuck. I'd hate for you to miss this journey!

Comment: Will do! Thanks for your response.